# Adaptive Layout in Xcode 7.0.1

Tags: xcode, swift, layout

I have an app that displays properly in portrait view but truncates in landscape view:

[image]

[image]

From the research I have done it looks like I need to understand Size Classes and Adaptive Layout. However, I am only concerned with layout on iPhone 6, not across different devices (eg iPad).

Before jumping into Adaptive Layout and Size Classes, which seems quite a complex topic, I just wanted to ask if there is a simple way to make this app display properly in both portrait and landscape for iPhone 6.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it without size classes, but it requires a reasonable modification to your UI.

If you think about it then having a picker always visible makes no sense for you. Looking at your image I am puzzled as to which date is currently being adjusted.

What you want to do instead, is to make your picker appear after user clicks on one of the dates. You can make it slide up from the bottom. In addition, you can add a label above it which will clearly indicate which date the user is currently modifying. That label can be placed in the toolbar to make it easy to add "Done" and "Cancel" buttons to the left and to the right.

In my view it would make much more sense and would also solve your problem. The rest of the UI can be put in the scroll view if you don't have enough space on old devices (e.g. 3.5 inch iPhones)

Comment: That's a great suggestion, solves my problem, thank you!